# SharePoint 2013 CAML query OrderBy not sorting properly

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I'm using a CAML query to grab some items from a list.  It pulls the items into a datatable which is then set as the datasource of a gridview control.

Everything worked fine until I realized it was using the ID field to sort the items.  I wanted to sort by the field Target_x0020_Id, so I ordered the order by, however it doesn't change the behavior when I added this.

This is my query:

WhereEqFieldRefName='Target_x0020_Id' Value Type='Text'900/Value/EqWhereOrderByFieldRef Name='Target_x0020_Id'/FieldRef/OrderBy

The only thing I added was the orderby element. (Sorry I'm having some issues posting the code without it trying to render in the post)

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume this is the CAML you're using

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRefName='Target_x0020_Id'>
    <Value Type='Text'>900</Value>
  </Eq>
<Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Target_x0020_Id'></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
```

I see three glaring errors.

1. There's a missing space between FieldRef and Name in the `<Eq>` portion of the caml.
2. The closing `<where>` is missing the forward slash.
3. The FieldRef tag in `<OrderBy>` is incorrect. It's self closing

This should be the right caml

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='Target_x0020_Id'>
    <Value Type='Text'>900</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Target_x0020_Id' />
</OrderBy>
```

I do see that you're returning all items where Target_x0020_Id is equal to 900 and then sorting all those items by Target_x0020_Id. Since this field is always 900, your sort isn't going to work.

Also, is Target_x0020_Id really a text field?  If it's numeric, you should chagne the type to 'Number' instead of 'Text'.

Comment: I actually have what you posted.  I had to edit it because SO kept formatting it so it didn't show up.

Comment: One thing I notice is you're limiting all returned items where the target id field is 900 and then sorting by that same field. In essence, you're sorting by 900.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized you're right.  I was using a value based on the URL.  I switched it to the title field, and it's sorting properly now.